# Error occurs When Debugging on real machine (libswiftCore)

Tags: ios, swift

when I try to debug on a real machine, the error below happens as soon as debugging.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmrO3.png)
development setting: 
Xcode7.2 Swift2.0 MacOSX10.11

I already tried revoking Certificate and Provisioning file and made it again,but nothing changed.

How can i fix it?
Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: When asking a question, be clear what you want to happen, what does happen and what you have tried to fix the problem.  Don't rely on links to describe the problem.

Comment: Sorry..i'm not familliar with this site. i intended to put my error message but that became a link to the image not intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should check if `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` in  the Build Settings is set to `YES`